# DllNotFoundException with DllImport in Mono on Mac

Tags: c#, mono, dllimport, dylib, monomac

I'm trying to use DLLImport in my Mono Mac project in order to use my own .dylib but I get the DllNotFoundException. I'm guessing it has something to do with my .dylib since I'm able to do this with existing .dylib files such as the libmojoshader.dylib.

Here's how I use DLLImport

```
[DllImport("libtestDylib.dylib")]
static extern int libsum(int a, int b);
```

I then call the libsum function in order to see if it works.

I've found that running the app through the terminal with the **MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono myGame.exe** command is a great way to debug issues like this, however I can't get my app .exe to run. I've tried using both the .exe in build folder and the one in the .app/contents/MonoBundle, I've also tried running file in .app/contents/MacOs as this is referenced in some places I've found while researching.

The last file throws a **"File does not contain a valid CIL image."** and the two others **"No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file".**

So, I would guess that the first step is to manage to run the app through the terminal in order to get proper debug information as for why my .dylib can't be found.

The .dylib I made is an empty BSD C  lib made in XNA4.

**Edit**

I can't even seem to get the existing dylibs to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by making a new Mono Mac project with a single c# file which I then compiled through the terminal and ran it with the debug command. With the terminal feedback found out where the program was searching for the .dylib, and that the lib I made was built with the wrong architecture which was simply solved by building for 32-bit systems.